# Add formatting to Array

Tags: array, list-authors

This displays authors by date of their latest post. I'd like to:

1. **add formatting around each author**
2. **list additional properties** (avatar, latest post title and excerpt) <-- I have the bits for this, but not sure where to insert them here.

   ```
   <ul>
   <?php
   //List of users sorted descending by date of latest post written by user
   $uc=array();
   $blogusers = get_users_of_blog();
   if ($blogusers) {
     foreach ($blogusers as $bloguser) {
       $userpost = get_posts('showposts=1&author='.$bloguser->user_id);
       $uc[$bloguser->user_id] = '';
       if ($userpost) {
         $uc[$bloguser->user_id]=$userpost[0]->post_date;
       }
     }
     arsort($uc);
     foreach ($uc as $key => $value) {
       $user = get_userdata($key);
       $post_count = get_usernumposts($user->ID);
       if ($post_count) {
         $author_posts_url = get_author_posts_url($key);
         echo '<li><a href="' . $author_posts_url . '">' . $user->user_firstname . ' ' .         $user->user_lastname . '</a> (' . $post_count . ') </li>';
       }
     }
   }
   ?>
   ```

Comment: What formatting and where? and... where do you want these properties. Maybe show us a text-based-wire-frame structure of how you want this to work otherwise its a guessing game.

Comment: I have the formating (and the extra info bits I mentioned) laid out here: http://pastebin.com/zxcyM8Zn

Comment: By the way, that pastebin code is **exactly** what I need with one exception: users are sorted by ID. If there's a way use that code instead and simply add the sorting - even better! Thank you

Comment: Ehm, so what is your question currently - how to add info or how to sort?

Comment: It's both, actually. Right now I have formatting and all the data in place, but there's no sorting. So it must be both 1) sorted by last post, AND 2) formatted.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: Try adding, `'orderby' => 'author'`to the code in pastebin.

Comment: @userabuser, it's already sorted by author - author ID to be specific. I need Authors sorted by latest post. The code above (in the original post) does that. The problem with that code is that it outputs a list, and I haven't found a way to split them up and give a separate div to each author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm finding it a little hard to follow based on your comments, however if you want to add a `<div>` around each other then change your second `foreach` statement to;

```
  foreach ($uc as $key => $value) {
    $user = get_userdata($key);
    $post_count = get_usernumposts($user->ID);
    if ($post_count) {
      $author_posts_url = get_author_posts_url($key);
      echo '<div class="class-name-here">';
      echo '<li><a href="' . $author_posts_url . '">' . $user->user_firstname . ' ' .         $user->user_lastname . '</a> (' . $post_count . ') </li>';
      echo '</div>';
    }
  }
```

That's based on the assumption you want to keep the `<li>` element, if not, just replace that with the `<div>`

#### Update ([with regards to your comment](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/67852/add-formatting-to-array/69231#comment90710_69231))

```
$args=array(
  'author' => $user->ID,
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => 1,
  'caller_get_posts'=> 1,
  'orderby' => 'author'   //add the orderby parameter and sort by author
);
```

As I [mentioned in my comment attached to your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/67852/add-formatting-to-array/69231#comment90706_67852) above, you can try adding the `orderby` parameter and then assign `author` as its value which should sort via ID or alternatively if that does not work then replace `author` with `$user->ID`

#### Update 2

After running some tests on your original snippet, removing deprecated functions and adding the `orderby=date` parameter to your initial `foreach` statement (although it neither effects with or without) I am still able to retrieve a list of authors, showing their last post, then ordering all results returned by the most recent date. So if,

- User A posts 12/10/2012
- User B posts 15/10/2012
- User C posts 11/10/2012

The order of results returned is,

- User B
- User A
- User C

---

```
$uc=array();
$blogusers = get_users();
if ($blogusers) {
  foreach ($blogusers as $bloguser) {
    $userpost = get_posts('showposts=1&author='.$bloguser->ID.'&orderby=date');
    $uc[$bloguser->ID] = '';
    if ($userpost) {
       $uc[$bloguser->ID]=$userpost[0]->post_date;
    }
  }
  arsort($uc);
  foreach ($uc as $key => $value) {
    $user = get_userdata($key);
    $post_count = count_user_posts($user->ID);
    if ($post_count) {
      $author_posts_url = get_author_posts_url($key);
        echo '<li><a href="' . $author_posts_url . '">'.$user->user_firstname . ' '  $user->user_lastname . '</a> (' . $post_count . ') </li>'
    }
  }
}
```

Although the above snippet could be rewritten more efficiently, **it does work for me** and **so it should for you** with relation to what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi @userabuser well... that was a waste of time - just tested the original code, and it doesn't sort authors by latest post. Sorry for the confusion, too. I have a nearly-perfect working version (Pastebin) and then found this bit (above). Couldn't settle on one, until now. Please let me know if you have any ideas as to how to sort the Pastebin code. Thank you!

Comment: I added 'orderby' => 'author', it didn't change anything. It's the default sort order according to the internet :)

Comment: Btw, I include @userabuser at the beginning, but it gets erased.

Comment: Yes, it does sort by user ID. That's correct. I want to sort authors by latest post, so that the most recently active one is always at the top.

Comment: `'orderby' => 'date'` and add `'order' => 'DESC'` ... and while you're at it, remove `caller_get_posts` and replace it with `ignore_sticky_posts` because the former is deprecated.

Comment: Didn't work. It needs something else, like `$last_posts = get_posts($args);
if (count($last_posts) > 0) {
$last_post_date = $last_posts[0]->post_date;
$author->last_post_date = $last_post_date;` but I'm not sure where to stick that.

Comment: Looks like someone got it to work. The website I'm working on is part of a multisite. If I were to adapt this http://wordpress.org/support/topic/query-post-to-show-one-post-per-author?replies=18#post-1080761 would I need to change the function, where it refers to specific db tables?

Comment: Ah multisite, I see. So, now its working? In which case why do you want to adapt another function to it? Perhaps you might need to reference different tables, though I'm not sure if thats the case - despite each blog getting its own table within a multisite setup. It sounds to me that this is a separate question so to avoid any further confusion, I'd ask another question relating to that...

Comment: No, I haven't got it to sort them right, but if you follow the link I included, apparently there's a solution. That was a few years ago though. As far as confusing this post, I got a downvote for it anyway, figured it might as well be ruined all the way :) Thanks for your help @userabuser.

Comment: @Phantasmix I should up-vote you for your confusion factor :) That aside, I ran some tests and made slight modifications to the original snippet provided and it works for me. So, it should work for you too.